# 7z. how exclude all in directory except one file

Tags: bash, 7zip

How exclude all in directory except one file?

folder example:

```
somedir
|-- index.html
|-- somedir
|   |-- some.file
`-- some.file
```

--

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXCLUDE='
-x!somedir/*
'

INCLUDE='
-i!somedir/index.html
'

7za a ../test.7z . $INCLUDE $EXCLUDE
```

But this script not work! Archive have only one empty folder `somedir`

Answer (score 0):

I found only this solution((

```
#!/bin/bash

EXCLUDE='
-x!somedir/*
'

7za a ../test.7z . $EXCLUDE


FILES='
somedir/index.html
'

7za a ../test.7z $FILES
```